# Solr Minimum Match not working?

Tags: solr

In my solrconfig.xml I specify a mm of 100% yet, searches with multiple terms, still show results that only match some of the search terms. If I explicitly put a + in front of each term, the desired behavior is achieved, but for obvious reasons, I don't want the user to have to enter the +'s.

Also, I have tried several variations of the mm parameter, and none of them seem to achieve what I am after. Below is the entire request handler:

```
<requestHandler name="dismax" class="solr.SearchHandler" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">dismax</str>
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <float name="tie">0.01</float>
    <str name="qf">
      body^0.5 subject^3.0 from^10.0 to^7.0
    </str>
    <str name="mm">
      100%
    </str>
    <int name="ps">100</int>
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered my own question. The xml config above is fine. I was passing a boost parameter to the query that looked something like

```
{!boost b=<some boost>}
```

And that was causing the dismax handler to parse the query differently, thereby ignoring the mm.

Comment: Hi! I am having the same exact issue and I don't think I am passing any boost except pf. Please let me know what I should do for Solr to reflect modified mm. My case is I want atleast one term match